# Обновление данных в pop-up

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, setinterval

Как вызвать функцию showquote чтобы данные обновлялись при каждом ее вызове?

```js
var quotes = [];
quotes[0] = "Сергей оформил заказ на массажное кресло Калифорния С.";
quotes[1] = "Юлия купила ";
quotes[2] = "Александр оформил заказ на ";
quotes[3] = "Елена заказала ";
var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote = Math.round(Math.random() * (q - 1));

function showquote() {
  document.getElementById('popupname').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote]
}

function PopUpShow() {
  document.getElementById('popup1').style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(showquote, 500); /*здесь не обновляется текст*/
  setTimeout("document.getElementById('popup1' ).style.display = 'none'", 2000);
}

setInterval(PopUpShow, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="popup1">
</div>

<div id="popupname">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно код

```
var q = quotes.length;
var whichquote = Math.round(Math.random() * (q - 1));
```

вынести из глобальной области в функцию `showquote` иначе случайная цитата вычислится лишь один раз при старте программы.

Вот весь код:

```js
var quotes = new Array();
quotes[0] = "Сергей оформил заказ на массажное кресло Калифорния С.";
quotes[1] = "Юлия купила ";
quotes[2] = "Александр оформил заказ на ";
quotes[3] = "Елена заказала ";

function showquote() {
  var q = quotes.length;
  var whichquote = Math.round(Math.random() * (q - 1));
  document.getElementById('popupname').innerHTML = quotes[whichquote]
}

function PopUpShow() {
  document.getElementById('popup1').style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(showquote, 500); /*здесь не обновляется текст*/
  setTimeout("document.getElementById('popup1' ).style.display = 'none'", 2000);
}

setInterval(PopUpShow, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="popup1">
</div>

<div id="popupname">
</div>
```

Comment: Изменено время ожидание с 15 сек до 1.5 секунды, чтобы быстрей наблюдать результат.

Comment: Также можно улучшить код, сделав чтобы функция `showquote` не выбирала уже выбранный текст.

Comment: После твоего редактирования вопроса - твой ответ потерял актуальность: `q = quotes.length;` и т.д. **уже** внутри функции.

Comment: Спасибо за внимательность, вернул как было.